# Change CSS for <li> items with different ID in Javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists, increment

Hy,
I want to apply a css style for all my < li > tags after their id...the problem is that these tags have different id(autoincremental)...I made a screenshot in my firebug:

[image]

For all < li > items, ID is "abc_dev_view_menu_i*",where * is a number wich increments for each new item I add.

So how to manage this,how to apply **the same style** for all < li > in this case where the number from ID increments each time I add one item?I tried with javascript,using getElementById but nothing worked until now

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood, you want to have a different style for every li? Or so that they share same style?

Comment: same style for all li which have id="abc_dev_view_menu_i*",and * is the number which autoincrement

Comment: Then why not just add a css rule for .ui-state-default as they already all share that? Or add a new class to them if you can't use that class.

Comment: i'm not defining 'ui-state-default' class because another items use that..i will try what you said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this attribute selector:

```
li[id^="abc_dev_view_menu_i"] {
   /* common style */
}
```

this CSS rule will apply a style to each `li` whose `id`attribute starts with `abc_dev_view_menu_i` (regardless of the incremental counter)

Comment: in CSS or Javascript?

Comment: thanks..i will try this and i will come back to tell you if it worked:)

Comment: i have another problem to manage right now...it's something for my job..but i will try what you said after that

Comment: @AdiCrainic http://jsfiddle.net/r3Wkv/5/ : li is an element and not a class (so you have to remove the dot in `.li`) and assignment is done via `:` and not with `=`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a single class for all `li` to which style is to be applied

Comment: not all my li have this id..i want only for li wich id starts with abc_dev_view_menu_i

Comment: I am talking about `class` attribute; not `id`. Example, you can simply give all the `<li>` elements a `class` custom_list. Then you can specify css for the class as `.custom_list { /*properties*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

build the id with a loop instruction,

for (i .....) id="abc_dev_view_menu_i"+i;